# Chameleon templates for javascript files?

Tags: javascript, python, pyramid, chameleon

I am developing a simple pyramid application where I am using JQuery to do AJAX requests. I have until now had my javascript code within my chameleon templates. Now I want to extract my javascript into another location (e.g. as static resources).

My problem is that I find my javascript code relies on dynamically generated content like so:

```
$.post("${request.route_url('my_view')}",{'data': 'some data'}, function(html){
    $("#destination").html(html);
});
```

The dynamic element being:

```
"${request.route_url('my_view')}"
```

Which is calling the route_url method of the request object within the template.

Is there a recognised pattern for separating such javascript files into their own templates and providing routes and views for them or do I simply keep my javascript in my page template?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes; you generally put context-specific information like expanded routes into the templates and access this information from your (static) JavaScript libraries.

Including the context info can be done in various ways, depending on taste:

1. You could use a data attribute on a tag in your generated HTML:

   ```html
   <body data-viewurl="http://www.example.com/route/to/view">
       ...
   </body>
   ```

   which you then, in your static JS code load with the [jQuery `.data()` function](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

   ```js
   var viewurl = $('body').data('viewurl');
   ```
2. Use a made-up [LINK tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-LINK) relationship to include links in the document head:

   ```html
   <head>
       <link rel="ajax-datasource" id="viewurl"
             href="http://www.example.com/route/to/view" />
       ...
   </head>
   ```

   which can be retrieved using `$('link#viewurl').attr('href')`, or `$('link[rel=ajax-datasource]').attr('href')`. This only really works for URL information.
3. Generate JS variables straight in your template, to be referenced from your static code:

   ```html
   <head>
       ...
       <script type="text/javascript">
          window.contextVariables = {
              viewurl = "http://www.example.com/route/to/view",
              ...
          };
       </script>
   </head>
   ```

   and these variables are referable directly with `contextVariables.viewurl`.

Comment: I went for option 2 as it seems to fit what I'm doing best.