# Django design pattern - method to populate client-side JavaScript variables on load

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, web-applications

Let's say I have a list of books I want to render in a certain way with JavaScript, as opposed to just doing something like the following;

```
{% for book in books %}
  <div class="book-container">
    <div class="title">{{ book.title }}</div>
    <div class="author">{{ book.author }}</div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to load the json representation of books into a JavaScript variable (perhaps a list of Book objects I've defined in my client side code) and render it in a more "fancy" way using JavaScript.

Anyways, I was thinking of sending a post request on page load to get the data and loading it into a variable. Is there a better way to do this? These are my initial naive guesses.

**EDIT**: In essence, I want to learn of a legitimate/recommended way to get a context server side and load it into a JavaScript variable client-side on page load.

Comment: Related: [Chameleon templates for javascript files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155947/11156400#11156400)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just output it as JSON directly in the template? That'll save the extra POST request.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var books = {{ my_json_data }}
</script>
```

Now `books` is a global JS variable that can be accessed from your other scripts.

Comment: could that be the explanation for this implementation, just the fact that the API resided in the project's scope? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583039/django-project-with-a-server-side-apimixin

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at django-tastypie which provides a REST framework. You might also want to look into backbone.js and general AJAX

https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie

http://backbonejs.org/